# TOC in a Word table cell

Tags: table-of-contents

I inserted a TOC in a '2 cell' table.  The TOC is in the right side cell.  When I inserted it, the page numbers went off the page.  I need to know how to adjust the line width of the TOC to the width of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

1. Highlight all the paragraphs in the TOC.
2. Right click the selection and click **Paragraph** from the menu.
3. Click on **Tabs** down the bottom left of the dialog.
4. Clear the existing tab from list.
5. Add a new tab with a "..." leader at the desired position and click
   **Set**.